# Recursive Sub-Palindrom with length of SubPalindrom

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive function, which calculates the biggest sub-palindrome.

For example the biggest sub.Pal. for "character" is "carac".

So far I've achieved my goal but only with a global variable "length" where i'm adding my values, but it would be nice if someone could show me how to do this with only recursive calls. I first tried to give the function a second parameter (length=0) and to add the value to it when i'm calling the function,but i'm not getting it to work properly.

Here's my Code:

```
length = 0

def subpalindrom(s):
    global length
    if len(s) == 1:
        length += 1
        return True, length

    if len(s) == 0:
        return True, length

    elif s[0] != s[-1]:

        for i in range(len(s) - 1, int(len(s) / 2) - 1, -1):  # search right half, if there is smth. equal

        if s[0] == s[i]:
            length += 2
            return subpalindrom(s[1:i])  # if smth. is equal slice it, add length

        elif i == int(len(s) / 2):
            # if index i is at half of the string and nothing was found, continue with next val on left half
            return subpalindrom(s[1:])
    else:
        length += 2
        return subpalindrom(s[1:-1])


print(subpalindrom("character"))
```

And if anyone could tell me how i can see which time complexity this function has it would be more than great. I would say that it is O(log n) but it's just a guess.

Edit: T(n) = T(n-2) + n/2 ?
T(n-2) for recursive calls (because we slice 2 elements away) and + n/2 because of the for loop?

Thank you for your Time !

Comment: When telling that an algorithm is O(log(n)) you must precise what you understand by n. Do you mean the number of characters of the input string or the length of the maximum palindrom ? The naive algorithm for this problem is cubic in the length of the input string, while the optimal algorithm is [Manacher's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring) which is linear in the length of the input string: O(n).
It can't be better since you have to read at least the whole input string.

Comment: Your recurrence relation for the complexity of your algorithm gives a quadratic complexity, since it gives you the sum (assuming n is even):
(n + (n-2) + (n-4) + ... + 2)/2 = 1 + ... + n/2 = n/2 * (n/2 + 1) / 2 = O(n^2)
The same complexity can be obtained by testing iteratively for each position i which is the largest palindrom centered at i (and by keeping the maximum amongst all positions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sry for the late share,but if anyone is interested, here is how i handled it:

```
def subpalindrom(l, r, w):
    if l == r:
        return 1
    if l > r:
        return 0
    if w[l] == w[r]:
        return 2 + subpalindrom(l + 1, r - 1, w)
    else:
        return max(subpalindrom(l + 1, r, w), subpalindrom(l, r - 1, w))


print(subpalindrom(0, len("character")-1, "character"))
```

Comment: your name variables are not clear. What is l, r, w ? Your function lacks a docstring.
You don't precise the complexity of your algorithm neither.